# Debian : how to set login behaviour (ask passsword)

Tags: debian, gnome, login, password, fingerprint

I tried to use my fingerprint reader on my laptop yesterday, installing fprintd ; it didn't work. I then removed all those packackages.

I then realized Gnome (or non graphical session) doesn't ask for my password anymore at login screen, whether I set it on ON or OFF in the GUI parameters.

Could anyone tell me how to change this setting in a terminal?

Comment: Laptop? MAKE? MODEL?

Comment: I dont believe debian os will differ from one model to another - hardware will - . this is a command I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Select the 4 options then validate :

```
[*] Unix authentication                                                
[*] Register user sessions in the systemd control group hierarchy         
[*] GNOME Keyring Daemon - Login keyring management                    
[*] Inheritable Capabilities Management
```